# Most number of co-authors in a single paper?

Tags: publications, authorship, statistics

**Previous research**

I've tried to find the answer to this question looking at the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" as I typed in the question, with no luck.

**Question**

What are some, say five, examples of publications with the highest recorded number of co-authors ever published, and in each of these how many co-authors were involved?

Comment: From [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-academic-paper-has-the-most-co-authors), an article about the LHC with apparently more than 3000 co-authors http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037026931200857X

Comment: Likely, any article covering a huge group project in fields such as astronomy, genome sequencing, or physics, that is impossible to do in a single lab or a small number of partner labs.

Comment: Are we ready for a paper where the list of authors is longer than the paper itself?

Comment: @Compass I'm glad to see the authors on that paper did something sensible and went with alphabetical order.

Comment: @GEdgar Two already exist: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1311997/ and its followup: http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1985.61.1.298?journalCode=pms

Comment: @GEdgar and another http://www.improbable.com/airchives/classical/articles/peanut_butter_rotation.html ;o)

Comment: This is really laughable, and one of the reasons why academic research reputation did nothing but deteriorating in the past decades. Coauthors must have produced results presented in the paper and be accountable for them. Adding any "collaborator", means that now on you have to add Steve Jobs / Bill Gates / Linus Torvalos to the list if you used a MAC/ windows/linux.

Comment: @SeF , well, for better or for worse. These days God is cited a lot less than back in the days of Newton

Comment: Also @GEdgar, how on earth do you search for this material.

Answer (score 5):

A good survey can be found in [this article](http://archive.sciencewatch.com/newsletter/2012/201207/multiauthor_papers/).  In short: within approximately the last 5 years, large international collaborations have started to exceed 1000 authors per paper.  The largest authorship papers are all [LHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) papers at present (with 3000+ authors), but other collaborations, particularly in biomedicine, may top that in the future.